# How to make Django serve static files with Gunicorn?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I want to run my django project under gunicorn on localhost. I installed and integrated gunicorn. When I run:

```
python manage.py run_gunicorn
```

It works but there are no any static files (css and js)

I disabled debug and template_debug in settings.py (made them false), but it is still same.  Am I missing something?

I call statics like:

```
{{ STATIC_URL }}css/etc....
```

Answer (score 220, accepted):

When in **development** mode and when *you are using some other server for local development* add this to your `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Note that `staticfiles_urlpatterns()` will only work when `DEBUG = True` is set in your `settings.py`.

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development)

When in **production** you never, ever put gunicorn in front. Instead you use
a server like nginx which dispatches requests to a pool of gunicorn workers and also serves the static files.

See [here](http://gunicorn.org/deploy.html)

Comment: when i re-enable debug and template_debug, it started to work correctly. it didnt matter to put those lines into urls.py. but now i cant see my custom 404 and 500 error pages. in the production ; should i make False Debug and template_debug ?

Comment: @drTerminal I updated my answer and included the specific wording of the django link I cited. The custom 404/500 pages are only displayed when DEBUG=False. Please read the specific links, I think it will answer most of your questions.

Comment: This worked for me although I use Django 1.6. In the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development, there is a different usage of urlpattern for 1.6., but with no result for me. So I used the 1.4 solution with success.

Comment: So are you saying that gunicorn will never serve static files itself—it will only serve whatever the WSGI app serves?

Comment: @binki I am not sure what you mean. It *can* serve whatever you want it to serve. And in development, it makes sense to do it. But when in production you don't let gunicorn serve static files, because it's too slow and it's not its specialty.

Comment: What I mean is: gunicorn has no way to serve static files itself. It only serves what the WSGI application serves. I.e., there is no way to use core gunicorn, without extending it or adding modules, to bypass the WSGI app and serve static files. Is that correct? (Your answer seems to indirectly suggest that, but not say so straight out).

Comment: @binki The links in my answer are dead it seems and I haven't worked with Django since.... 2013, so I don't remember what point I was trying to make :(  *But* this link https://vxlabs.com/2015/12/08/gunicorn-as-your-django-development-server/ seems to suggest that it's not impossible.

Comment: @rantanplan That’s just another example (like the [`whitenoise` suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37220346/429091)) of adding additional WSGI apps to serve static files. The fact that people keep giving like examples suggests that gunicorn does not have a core, built-in ability to serve static files. These may be valid approaches, but django itself clearly documents that its development support for serving static files itself “[grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#staticfiles-in-templates)”

Comment: So I guess the clear answer is that with just django and gunicorn you can’t serve static files—you need an additional third party component registered with either django’s routing system or gunicorn’s.

Comment: @binki Argh! You made me search :P So... since I had vague memories that you can actually do that, I searched a bit. If you download this pdf https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django/1.4.X/django.pdf, which is the obsolete version my answer was referring to, you'll see that it didn't matter if your app server could or couldn't, because Django did it for you. Of course it was grossly inefficient, but doable nonetheless. Don't know if it's possible anymore, and if yes, how it can be done.

Comment: Ah, it looks like maybe that would be [`django.views.static.serve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/views/#serving-files-in-development) which still exists in modern documentation. But basically with the same warning which hasn’t changed from the 1.4 docs “This view is not hardened for production use and should be used only as a development aid”. Not as strongly worded. So it’s doable with pure django and even documented, just it’s an “unsupported” use of it I guess. Just the `serve` function is always available but the `static` helper function automatically disables in production.

Comment: Has anybody told you that you are AWESOME before !

Comment: @YasserSinjab Heh. Glad you found it useful :)

Comment: Is there any way to do it without adding python code. It should be simpler like setting a environment variable to 1.

Comment: Django reference is dead.

Comment: works on 4.1, no need to add any config on nginx

Answer (score 39):

**Whitenoise**

**Post v4.0**

http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0

> The WSGI integration option for Django (which involved editing wsgi.py) has been removed. Instead, you should add WhiteNoise to your middleware list in settings.py and remove any reference to WhiteNoise from wsgi.py. See the documentation for more details. 
>   (The pure WSGI integration is still available for non-Django apps.)

**Pre v4.0**

Heroku recommends this method at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets:

> Your application will now serve static assets directly from Gunicorn in production. This will be perfectly adequate for most applications, but top-tier applications may want to explore using a CDN with Django-Storages.

Install with:

```
pip install whitenoise
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

`wsgi.py`:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "free_books.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Tested on Django 1.9.

Comment: So, again, this means that the WSGI app is serving static files. Not gunicorn.

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` will overwrite previous requirements, i would recommend `pip freeze | grep whitenoise >> requirements.txt`

Comment: Instructions above are deprecated as of whitenoise version 4.0 .  http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0

Answer (score 28):

I've used this for my development environment (which uses gunicorn):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application


if settings.DEBUG:
    application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
else:
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And then run `gunicorn myapp.wsgi`. This works *similar* to [@rantanplan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801140/107510), however, it does not run any middleware when running static files.

Comment: This is the answer I have ben looking for!! Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: Sometimes we are dealing with an in-house application and "web scale" isn't important. For those cases, this is a great answer.

Answer (score 25):

The gunicorn should be used to serve the python "application" itself, while the static files are served by a static file server ( such as Nginx ).

This is an excerpt from one of my configurations:

```
upstream app_server_djangoapp {
    server localhost:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen < server port goes here >;
    server_name < server name goes here >;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/guni-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/guni-error.log info;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    root < application root directory goes here >;

    location /static {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias < static folder directory goes here >;    
    }

    location /media {
       autoindex on;
       alias < user uploaded media file directory goes here >;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server_djangoapp;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- The static root, media root, static files path prefix and media file path prefix are set up in your settings.py
- Once you have nginx set up to serve from the static content directory, you need to run "python manage.py collectstatic" in your project root so that the static files in the various apps can be copied to the static folder

In closing: while it is possible to serve static files from gunicorn ( by enabling a debug-only static file serving view ), that is considered bad practice in production.

Comment: yes i know. i m gonna use it under nginx in production. i am just makin a test in my localhost before production.

Comment: When you say “while it is possible to serve static files from gunicorn”, are you actually meaning to say “gunicorn will **indirectly** serve static files if the WSGI app it delegates requests to serves static files”?

Answer (score 14):

While you're able to use Django to serve static files in development mode with the app [`django.contrib.staticfiles`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#module-django.contrib.staticfiles), [that is not suitable for production use](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development).

In order to serve static files, as [Jamie Hewland says](https://youtu.be/rdjtPTV_WWo?t=763), normally one routes all the requests to /static/ using Nginx

```
location /static/ {

    alias /path/to/static/files;

}
```

[image: Nginx + Gunicorn + Django]

Also, and as [coreyward says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42702316/5675325) about Gunicorn / Unicorn

> was not designed to solve the suite of problems involved in serving
> files to clients

Same line of reasoning applies if you consider other WSGI server like uWSGI instead of Gunicorn. In [uWSGI documentation](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)

> it’s inefficient to serve static files via uWSGI. Instead, serve them
> directly from Nginx and completely bypass uWSGI

So, serving static files in production is something to be done by NGINX, not by Django or other WSGI servers.

---

Another way is to serve your static files in production is using [WhiteNoise](https://pypi.org/project/whitenoise/) library which is very easy to setup (you might want to use a CDN so that most requests won't reach the Python app). As [Miguel de Matos says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62162685/5675325), you just have to

1. Collect static

   ```
    python manage.py collectstatic
   ```
2. Installing whitenoise

   ```
    pip install whitenoise
   ```
3. Add the following `STATICFILES_STORAGE` in settings.py

   ```
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
   ```
4. Add the following to your `MIDDLEWARE` in settings.py (as [mracette](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3064334/mracette) notes, "According to the whitenoise docs you should place the middleware after `django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware`")

   ```
    `MIDDLEWARE = [
      'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
      'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
      ...
    ]
   ```

Comment: According to the whitenoise docs you should place the middleware *after* 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware'

http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

Comment: Big thumbs up for `whitenoise`, spent days trying to get docker + gunicorn to serve static files but it refused, I assumed due to Docker's file structure. Following this cleared it right up.

Answer (score 2):

Since Django 1.3 there is django/conf/urls/static.py that handle static files in the DEBUG mode:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Read more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache/Gunicorn then here is how I set mine up.

1. In your Django root dir (with `manage.py`), create dirs `mkdir -p django_static/static`
2. In your project `settings.py` set the following:

```
DEBUG = False
INSTALLED_APPS = [..., 'django.contrib.staticfiles', ...]
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "django_static", "static")
```

3. Run `python manage.py collectstatic`. This will output static content to `django_static/static`
4. Start your `gunicorn` server with `gunicorn your_project_name.wsgi` (plus options)
5. Assuming you have default global Apache settings, you'll need to create a soft link from `/var/www` to your static dir:
   `sudo ln -s /path/to/your_django_project/django_static /var/www/your_django_project_static`
6. For your domain `www.example.com` that you wish to point to your Django app, configure the following virtual host in apache in order to proxy all requests submitted to `https://www.example.com` onto `127.0.0.1:8000` **except** for `www.example.com/static/` routes (in which case, serve files to such requests from `django_static`):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/your_django_project_static
    <Location "/">
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    </Location>
    <Location "/static/">
        ProxyPass "!"
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Voila!