# Deploying Django on nginx

Tags: django, deployment, nginx, fastcgi

hi I need to deploy a django application on nginx . I install nginx and python-flup in my fedora  I try this [guide](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx) but nginx can't read my static file .
in my project dir I used this command to run ​fastcgi:

```
[nima@ca005 bank]$ python ./manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8080
[nima@ca005 bank]$
```

and this is my sample_project.conf in /etc/nginx/sites-enable/ :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.16.161;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sample_project.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/sample_project.error.log;

    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-production
    location /static/ { # STATIC_URL
        alias /home/nima/workspace/bank/media/; # STATIC_ROOT
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ { # MEDIA_URL
        alias /home/nima/workspace/bank/meli/static/; # MEDIA_ROOT
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^()(.*)$;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enable/*;



}
```

what should I do?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, if you chose to use nginx, then use `gunicorn`, its the best option out there, and if you so wish to use Apache, then you use `mod_wsgi`.

[This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/) will show you how to use gunicorn. Just to tell you how well it serves, gunicorn is used by Instagram, because they claim that it gives them better performance.

Setting up `gunicorn` is very simple and easy to do, and [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20130407174353/http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn/) tutorial here, gives you all the things necessary to make it happen very quickly.

[This](http://gunicorn.org/) is their website.

Comment: I use gunicorn but It can't see my static when I run this command gunicorn_django -b 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: @nim4n: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800862/django-static-files-under-gunicorn

Comment: the static part yes . but I have a problem with upstart part. when I try to start service It give me this error : root@ca005 nima]# service hello start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  hello.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit hello.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status hello.service' for details.

Comment: It may help, I wrote a guide for deploying Django with upstart, nginx and gunicorn : http://ponytech.net/blog/2013/09/10/django-deployement-ubuntu-upstart-nginx-gunicorn-and-virtualenvwrapper/

Comment: What does gunicorn actually _do_ though? Whats its role?

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx) link using fastcgi mode 
Or [this](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) link using uwsgi mode

Edit: fcgi mode is deprecated in django and will be removed. uwsgi is the favourable mode. One of the many references, [check this](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/fcgi-vs-gunicorn-vs-uwsgi)