# In Django, how can I link a static file from within an extended HTML template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I haven't found anything in the Django Docs or any Stack Overflow solutions to this same problem.

Say I have a html file like the following:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block cssfile %}
<!-- css link goes here -->
{% endblock %}
{% block maincontent %}
Hello World
{% endblock %}
```

which will of course link to base.html.
However, I want to put a css file between the 'block cssfile' tags, but given the way that Django is structured for linking static files, it prevents me from doing this.

Something like

```
{% block cssfile %}
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="{% static 'myappname/css/style.css' %}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

will give me this error

> TemplateSyntaxError at /myapp/1/ Invalid block tag on line 3:
>   'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this
>   tag?

I've also tried replacing the '{% %}' tags for the href with something like '{{ }}' for example.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: did you `{% load staticfiles %}`?.. (did you forget to register or load this tag?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid block tag: 'static'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886477/invalid-block-tag-static)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `{% load staticfiles %}` before use `{% static %}`