# What are the disadvantages of using AWS ELB directly with Gunicorn (no nginx)?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, gunicorn, amazon-elb

Typical setups I've found on Google to run a django application on AWS all suggest a setup like

ELB -> nginx -> gunicorn -> django

I was wondering why the nginx part is really needed here? Isn't ELB sufficient as proxy?

In our case, we are running multiple Gunicorn/django instances in individual docker containers on ECS.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Without Nginx, It would work just fine and you will still be safe from the majority of DDOS attacks that can bring down an exposed gunicorn server.

I can only see Nginx helpful to add to the stack if it'll be serving your static files. However, it's much better to serve your static files by S3 (+ cloudfront as a bonus) since it's has high availability and reliability baked in.

Sources:
http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html#nginx-configuration
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801140

Comment: If client is slow, it will make your gunicorn server slow. Nginx makes it easy for gunicorn to deal with slow clients and send request only received completely (all TCP packets), not sure if ELB does that.

Comment: @user1501382 you can always use async worker such as gevent to increase the performance of gunicorn. Of course you'll have to auto scale your gunicorn app instance when it encounter massive loads. For performance and saving cost , nginx does not help on both case. As OP said, nginx only helps when you want to serve your static content on the same host. Which again using CDN is a better option in most scenario.

Answer (score 5):

I had to search a lot to get a satisfying answer :

1. ELB *does not save you from DDoS attack*s, it is more of a general purpose load balancer.
2. ELB *directly sends* the incoming request to the the Gunicorn server. It does not receive the full request before forwarding it to Gunicorn, i.e, if headers/body from the request is coming slowly because of bad internet connection from the client or whatever other reason, then the Gunicorn server will be waiting for the request to complete before it starts processing the request. In general, **it's a bad practice to allow the same server to be the web server and application server**, as this hogs up the resources of the application server(Gunicorn).
3. Nginx additionally helps **serve static files** and with GZIP compression, thus making it faster for sending/receiving data from both client/server.

Additionally, even in **Gunicorn's documentation**, it is recommended to use Nginx in front of it.

Comment: You can add CloudFront, which comes by default with AWS Shield, and you get caching, global distribution, DDOS protection and many other benefits without having to use NGINX.