# gunicorn + mezzanine : static files are not found

Tags: django, python-3.x, gunicorn, django-staticfiles, mezzanine

I installed a Mezzanine CMS by default and I will try to serve by gunicorn

**--** With `python manage.py runserver`, all static files are served **only if** `DEBUG = True`

Logs said:

```
... (DEBUG=False)
[07/Sep/2018 12:23:56] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[07/Sep/2018 12:23:57] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.css/ HTTP/1.1" 404 6165
...
```

**--** With `gunicorn helloworld.wsgi --bind 127.0.0.1:8000`, no static found!

Logs said:

```
$ gunicorn helloworld.wsgi --bind 127.0.0.1:8000

[2018-09-07 14:03:56 +0200] [15999] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-09-07 14:03:56 +0200] [15999] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (15999)
[2018-09-07 14:03:56 +0200] [15999] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-09-07 14:03:56 +0200] [16017] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16017
Not Found: /static/css/bootstrap.css/
Not Found: /static/css/mezzanine.css/
Not Found: /static/css/bootstrap-theme.css/
Not Found: /static/mezzanine/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js/
Not Found: /static/js/bootstrap.js/
Not Found: /static/js/bootstrap-extras.js/
```

Please have a look to url wanted: gunicorn or mezzanine (or else?) add a / character in the end of url.

I did this command too `python manage.py collectstatic` with no effect :(

`STATIC_ROOT` is correct and I applied https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Do you have a tips or solution? I'm afraid I didn't search correctly!

Thanks
Momo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **Ok for me**, thanks!

A correct search found me the answers

**--** for internal server `DEBUG=False` will not serve static files, it's a job for  webserver (nginx, apache) : [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

> If you still need to server static locally (e.g. for testing without debug) you can run devserver in insecure mode:
>   `manage.py runserver --insecure`

**--** for gunicorn webserver, we need add static manually in `urls.py` : [How to make Django serve static files with Gunicorn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800862/how-to-make-django-serve-static-files-with-gunicorn)

> in `urls.py`, add this:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development)

well done!