# Gunicorn throws error 403 when accessing static files

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, rhel, static-files

`python==2.7.5`, `django==1.11.10`, `gunicorn==19.7.1`, `RHEL 7.4`

I have a `django` project at my job written not by me.
It was in `eventcat` user's home directory and with time we ran out of available space on the disk. I was to move the project to `/data/`.
After I moved the project directory and set up a new environment I faced the problem that static files are not loaded and throwing `403 forbidden` error.

Well, I know that `gunicorn` is not supposed to serve static files on production, but this is an internal project with low load. I have to deal with it as is.

The server is started with a selfwritten script (I changed the environment line to new path):

```
#!/bin/sh
. ~/.bash_profile
. /data/eventcat/env/bin/activate
exec gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py eventcat.wsgi:application
```

The `gunicorn.conf.py` consists of:

```
bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'
backlog = 2048
workers = 1
worker_class = 'sync'
worker_connections = 1000
timeout = 120
keepalive = 2
spew = False
daemon = True
pidfile = 'eventcat.pid'
umask = 0
user = None
group = None
tmp_upload_dir = None
errorlog = 'er.log'
loglevel = 'debug'
accesslog = 'ac.log'
access_log_format = '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"'
proc_name = None 

def post_fork(server, worker):
    server.log.info("Worker spawned (pid: %s)", worker.pid)

def pre_fork(server, worker):
    pass

def pre_exec(server):
    server.log.info("Forked child, re-executing.")

def when_ready(server):
    server.log.info("Server is ready. Spawning workers")

def worker_int(worker):
    worker.log.info("worker received INT or QUIT signal")
    import threading, sys, traceback
    id2name = dict([(th.identm, th.name) for th in threading.enumerate()])
    code = []
    for threadId, stack in sys._current_frames().items():
        code.append("\n# Thread: %s(%d)" % (id2name.get(threadId, ""), threadId))
        for filename, lineno, name, line in traceback.exctract_stack(stack):
            code.append('File: "%s", line %d, in %s' %(filename, lineno, name))
            if line:
                code.append(" %s" % (line.strip()))
    worker.log.debug("\n".join(code))

def worker_abort(worker):
    worker.log.info("worker received SIGABRT signal")
```

All the files in `static` directory are owned by `eventcat` user just like the directory itself.
I couldn't find any useful information in `er.log` and `ac.log`.

The server is running on `https` protocol and there is an `ssl.conf` in project directory. It has aliases for `static` and `media` pointing to previous project location and I changed all these entries to the new ones. Though I couldn't find where this config file is used.

Please, advise how can I find out what is the cause of the issue. What config files or anything should I look into?

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to @ruddra, `gunicorn` wasn't serving static at all. It was `httpd` that was. After making changes in httpd config everything is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, gunicorn does not serve static contents. So to serve static contents, its best to use either [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) or you can use NGINX, Apache or any reverse proxy server. You can check Gunicorn's [documentation](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/0.17.0/deploy.html) on deployment using NGINX.

If you want to use whitenoise, then please install it using:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Then add whitenoise to `MIDDLEWARES` like this(inside `settings.py`):

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

Comment: Well, if `gunicorn` doesn't serve them, then who does? How can I find it out? I have working copy of this project on another server with working static files.

Comment: I think you can look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800862/how-to-make-django-serve-static-files-with-gunicorn

Comment: Thank you for your link.
Like you said, gunicorn didn't serve static at all. `httpd` did. I made some changes in config and everything is okay now.
Thank you for pointing that out.