# Gunicorn with Django giving a problem with static files

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, gunicorn, static-files

Got a Django project named django_server. When I run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

the page shows up as expected

[image: DRF working fine]

Then, if I run

```
gunicorn django_server.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The page shows without styling

[image: Gunicorn Django without style]

Checking the console, can see the following errors for both .css and .js files

> The resource from
>   “http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/....css” was blocked
>   due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options:
>   nosniff).

[image: Guniorn DRF console errors]
In the terminal where the gunicorn command was executed, can read

```
NOT FOUND: /static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css
NOT FOUND: /static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap-tweaks.min.css
...
```

In settings.py I mention

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

This is the folder structure

[image: Folder structure]

Checked the permissions in static folder (`ls -l`)and they show as

```
drwxrwxr-x 4 tiago tiago 4096 jun 2 15:49 static
```

Checking the permissions in the files where the problem happens and

[image: Ubuntu file permissions]

Added also to settings.py

```
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type("text/css",".css",True)
mimetypes.add_type("text/javascript",".js",True)
```

But the error remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run `python manage.py collectstatic`.

On your `settings.py` I recommend you to use `whitenoise` to serve your files.

**1)** `pip install whitenoise`

**2)** Add `STATICFILES_STORAGE` on settings.py

`STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'`

**3)** Add to your `MIDDLEWARE` on settings.py

```
`MIDDLEWARE = [

  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  ...

]
```

Comment: Hi Miguel de Matos. I ran collectstatic too, hence the static folder. Will checkout [whitenoise](https://pypi.org/project/whitenoise/) once I can and let you know.